# Appending numpy array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to append an array to another array but its appending them as if it was just one array. What I would like to have is have each array appended on its own index, (withoug having to use a list, i want to use np arrays) i.e

```
temp = np.array([])
for i in my_items
   m = get_item_ids(i.color)  #returns an array as [1,4,20,5,3]  (always same number of items but diff ids
   temp = np.append(temp, m, axis=0)
```

On the second iteration lets suppose i get [5,4,15,3,10]

then i would like to have temp as
`array([1,4,20,5,3][5,4,15,3,10])`
But instead i keep getting `[1,4,20,5,3,5,4,15,3,10]`

I am new to python but i am sure there is probably a way to concatenate in this way with numpy without using lists?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reshape m in order to have two dimension with

```
m.reshape(-1, 1)
```

thus adding the second dimension. Then you could concatenate along axis=1.

```
np.concatenate(temp, m, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

List append is **much** better - faster and easier to use correctly.

```
temp = []
for i in my_items
    m = get_item_ids(i.color)  #returns an array as [1,4,20,5,3]  (always same number of items but diff ids
    temp = m
```

Look at the list to see what it created.  Then make an array from that:

```
 arr = np.array(temp)
 # or `np.vstack(temp)
```