# How to create a new numpy 2d array with conditions from the existing 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2d array with 3 columns and N rows.
In the third column there are only 0 or 1.
I need to create 2 numpy arrays. They both contains first 2 columns of the given matrix, but first array has only rows corresponding to 0 from the third column, and second array has only rows to 1.

I've tried but it failed with dimension problems. I haven't used this kind of format before.
`onlyNormal_Xtest = np.vstack((onlyNormal_Xtest, Xy[Xy[N_train:, 2] == 0]))`

Is it possible to do it faster than following?

```
onlyNormal_Xtest = np.array([])
Xy_test = Xy[N_train:, :]

    for i in range(np.size(Xy_test, 0)):
        if (Xy_test[i, 2] == 0):
            onlyNormal_Xtest = np.append(onlyNormal_Xtest, Xy_test[i, :2])
```

Actually it still doesn't work due to dimension problems.

Comment: List append is faster.

Comment: `np.append` is also difficult to get right, especially when used iteratively.  You really need to understand array dimensions.  Do you even know what that `np.array([])` is like?  What's its shape?  Or why you even used it?   Did you read the whole `np.append` docs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983816/appending-numpy-array-of-arrays - another recent `append` question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question but here is the code i think you were trying to do

```
a = np.array([[1,2,0],
             [3,4,1],
             [5,6,0],
             [7,8,1]])
```

Gives

```
a[a[:,2]==1][:,:2]
array([[3, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```

```
a[a[:,2]==0][:,:2]
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```